# how to implement tcpdump -i interface arp with libpcap

Tags: linux, libpcap, arp

I want to implement command `tcpdump -i eth0 arp` to observe arp packets on interface  eth0 on my ubuntu.  I use libpcap, but the return value of function `pcap_next_ex` is always 0. With `tcpdump -i eth0 arp` in the same time , it can observe arp packets.

```
/*
 *  compile(root): gcc test.c -lpcap 
 *  run          : ./a.out
 *  output       : time out
 *                 time out
 *                 time out
 *                 ...
 */
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARP_REQUEST  1
#define ARP_REPLY    2

typedef struct arp_hdr_s  arp_hdr_t;
struct arp_hdr_s {
    u_int16_t       htype;
    u_int16_t       ptype;
    u_char          hlen;
    u_char          plen;
    u_int16_t       oper;
    u_char          sha[6];
    u_char          spa[4];
    u_char          tha[6];
    u_char          tpa[4];
};

#define MAXBYTES2CAPTURE  2048

int 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char                    err_buf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    const unsigned char    *packet; 
    int                     i;
    int                     ret;
    arp_hdr_t              *arp_header;
    bpf_u_int32             net_addr;
    bpf_u_int32             mask;
    pcap_t                 *desrc;
    struct pcap_pkthdr     *pkthdr; 
    struct bpf_program      filter;

    net_addr = 0;
    mask = 0;
    memset(err_buf, 0, PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE);

    desrc = pcap_open_live("eth0", MAXBYTES2CAPTURE, 0, 512, err_buf);
    if (desrc == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", err_buf);
        exit(-1);
    }

    ret = pcap_lookupnet("eth0", &net_addr, &mask, err_buf);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", err_buf);
        exit(-1);
    }

    ret = pcap_compile(desrc, &filter, "arp", 1, mask);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", pcap_geterr(desrc));
        exit(-1);
    }

    ret = pcap_setfilter(desrc, &filter);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "errnor: %s\n", pcap_geterr(desrc));
        exit(-1);
    }

    while (1) {
        ret = pcap_next_ex(desrc, &pkthdr, &packet);
        if (ret == -1) {
            printf("%s\n", pcap_geterr(desrc));
            exit(1);
        } else if (ret == -2) {
            printf("no more\n");
        } else if (ret == 0) {             // here
            printf("time out\n");
            continue;
        }

        arp_header = (arp_hdr_t *)(packet + 14);
        if (ntohs(arp_header->htype) == 1 && ntohs(arp_header->ptype == 0x0800)) {
                printf("src IP: ");
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    printf("%d.", arp_header->spa[i]);
                }
                printf("dst IP: ");
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    printf("%d.", arp_header->tpa[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably work better if you did

```
if (ntohs(arp_header->htype) == 1 && ntohs(arp_header->ptype) == 0x0800) {
```

rather than

```
if (ntohs(arp_header->htype) == 1 && ntohs(arp_header->ptype == 0x0800)) {
```

The latter evaluates `arp_header->type == 0x0800`, which, when running on a little-endian machine (such as a PC), will almost always evaluate to "false", because the value will look like 0x0008, not 0x0800, in an ARP packet - ARP types are big-endian, so they'll look byte-swapped on a little-endian machine).  That means it'll evaluate to 0, and byte-swapping 0 gives you zero, so that `if` condition will evaluate to "false", and the printing code won't be called.

You'll still get lots of timeouts if you fix that, unless there's a *flood* of ARP packets, but at least you'll get the occasional ARP packet printed out.  (I would advise printing nothing on a timeout; pcap-based programs doing live capturing should expect that timeouts should happen, and should not report them as unusual occurrences.)

Comment: Yeah, it works! I have 2 questions. In the code above, "eth0" is directly given as the first parameter of `pcap_open_live`. If I want to observe "eth0" , rather than "eth1" "eth2".. on my host(multiple interfaces), How can I make it with `pcap_lookupdev`, or other ways avaliable?  Is there any good way with libpcap to observe arp packets? I think my program is a little complex and messy.

Comment: If you want to observe "eth0", you're doing exactly what you should do - you're passing "eth0" as the argument to `pcap_open_live()`.  What are you *really* asking here?

Comment: "Is there any good way with libpcap to observe arp packets? I think my program is a little complex and messy."  Have you taken a look at tcpdump's `print-arp.c` - or Wireshark's `packet-arp.c`?  Your program's handling of ARP packets is a *lot* simpler than the more complete ARP packet analysis done by both of those programs.  And their code to do capturing is more complex, too.

Comment: (Also, if you have questions after your original question is answered, and they're asking about stuff other than what your original question was asking - that's the case with both of your questions - you might want to ask them as separate questions.  Q&A sites aren't forums, they're more like crowdsourced FAQs, and if each of your questions is asked separately, somebody who wants an answer to, for example, your *second* question, but not your *original* question, might be more likely to find it if they search the Q&A site.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting too deep in your code, I can see a major problem:

In your use of `pcap_open_live()`, you do not set promiscuous mode: the third parameter should be non-zero. If the ARP request is not targeted to your interface IP, pcap will not see it without promiscuous mode. `tcpdump` does, unless specifically told not to do so by using the `--no-promiscuous-mode`, use promisc (and hence will require `CAP_NET_ADMIN` privilege, which you'll get by `sudo`, which your program will require too).

Side note:

1/ Leak: you may want to free your filter using `pcap_freecode()` after your `pcap_setfilter()`.

2/ I assume you've read the official tuto here:

http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

...if that's not the case you'd be well advised to do that first. I quote:

> A note about promiscuous vs. non-promiscuous sniffing: The two
>   techniques are very different in style. In standard, non-promiscuous
>   sniffing, a host is sniffing only traffic that is directly related to
>   it. Only traffic to, from, or routed through the host will be picked
>   up by the sniffer. Promiscuous mode, on the other hand, sniffs all
>   traffic on the wire. In a non-switched environment, this could be all
>   network traffic. [... more stuff on promisc vs non-promisc]

EDIT:

Actually, looking deeper to you code compared to my code running for +1 year at production level (both in-house and at the customer) I can see many more things that could be wrong:

- You never call `pcap_create()`
- You never call `pcap_set_promisc()`, we've talked about this already
- You never call `pcap_activate()`, this may be the core issue here

...pcap is **very** touchy about the sequence order of operations to first get a pcap_t handle, and then operate on it.

At the moment, the best advice I can give you - otherwise this is going to a live debugging session between you and me, are:

1/ read and play/tweak with the code from the official tutorial:

http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

**This is mandatory.**

2/ FWIW, my - definitely working - sequence of operations is this:

- `pcap_lookupnet()`
- `pcap_create()`
- `pcap_set_promisc()`
- `pcap_set_snaplen()`, you may or may not need this
- `pcap_set_buffer_size()`, you may or may not need this
- `pcap_activate()` with a note: Very important: first activate, then set non-blocking from PCAP_SETNONBLOCK(3PCAP): When first activated with pcap_activate() or opened with pcap_open_live() , a capture handle is not in `non-blocking mode''; a call to pcap_set-nonblock() is required in order to put it into`non-blocking'' mode.

...and then, because I do not use stinking blocking/blocking with timeout, busy looping:

- `pcap_setnonblock()`
- `pcap_get_selectable_fd()`

...then and only then:
 - `pcap_compile()`
 - followed by a `pcap_setfilter()`
 - and then as I mentioned a `pcap_freecode()`
 - and then a select() or family on the file'des' I get from `pcap_get_selectable_fd()`, to `pcap_dispatch()`, but this is another topic.

`pcap` is an old API starting back in the 80's, and its really **very** *very* touchy. But don't get discouraged! It's great - once you get it right.

Comment: Using `tcpdump -i eth0 arp` in the same time, I observe arp request and reply in the ip of interface eth0, but no packets oberseved with my program. So I don't know what's wrong. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: The output of my program indicates `pcap_next_ex` always return `0`.

Comment: And you do not `sudo` your tcpdump??? If so, there's something else wrong in your code. May give it a try. In the meantime, please set the promisc parameter to your `pcap_open_live()`, or make it an option to your main(). 99% of the time you do want promisc.

Comment: @hel "The output of my program indicates pcap_next_ex always return 0" Yes, I saw that, thanks. Using `pcap_next_ex()` is not the way to go for a half-serious pcap program anyway, but that would be the topic for another question.

Comment: I retry it with `desrc = pcap_open_live("eth0", MAXBYTES2CAPTURE, 1, 512, err_buf);` and `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 arp`. And it's the same.

Comment: I make the program according to the sequence `pcap_lookupnet pcap_open_live pcap_compile pcap_setfilter pcap_next_ex`, which can also be seen [http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html] (You can find it by searching `pcap_open_live` in that page ). I don't think the problem is the sequence called.

Comment: "You never call `pcap_create()` ... You never call `pcap_activate()`" Not a problem - he's using `pcap_open_live()`, which is the old API for opening a device for capturing, instead of using `pcap_create()`, various "set" calls, and `pcap_activate()`.  `pcap_open_live()` is still supported, although it can't do everything you can do with `pcap_create()`, various "set" calls, and `pcap_activate()`.  It *can*, however, set promiscuous mode, which is what the person who asked the question *wasn't* making it do.